# Figure out which link was clicked, based on the number of links in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a hard time explaining this, so please, let me know if I'm unclear.

I'm creating a script that counts the number of images in a div, then generates the same number of links in another div. I need to know how many links there are in the div, and which position each resides in.

Here's an example:

Images:

```
<div class="images">
<img src="/example01.jpg" />
<img src="/example02.jpg" />
</div>
```

Links, which get generated via jQuery

```
<div class="links">
<a href="#">Example 01</a>
<a href="#">Example 02</a>
</div>
```

Other links which need to be clicked when a user clicks on one of the generated links:

```
<div class="otherLinks">
<a href="#" rel="0">REL 0</a>
<a href="#" rel="1">REL 1</a>
</div>
```

Basically, I need to count the number of links, and then click on the link with the correct REL. I'm having trouble figuring out which would be the correct REL, if that makes sense. So if a user clicks on Example 01, I want my jQuery to click on REL 0.

I'm sure there's a way to use a counter to do this, I just can't figure it out.

Comment: This isn't at all clear. When the user clicks on a link you can intercept that with a click handler. You'll know which link has been clicked from the event data sent to the handler, or the `this` object. In the latter part of your question, are you saying that you need to click _two_ links? How do you expect that to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).on('click', '.links a', function(){
    $('a[rel="'+$(this).index()+'"]').trigger('click');
});
```

I'm not sure if your links are dynamically generated or not, so I've used event delegation here to handle that. Please replace `document` with the closest static parent element that is never removed / replaced.

Also, `.trigger('click')` will only trigger `click events that have been bound by jQuery`. It will not, for instance, trigger the `href` value and redirect based on that action.

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you. I'll mark down that `.index()` for future reference, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.length` to count the no. of links generated, then on click of `.links a` get the index of clicked anchor and then trigger the click event on the same index of anchor inside `otherlinks` div

```
var count=$("div.links a").length;

$("div.otherlinks  a").click(function(){
alert($(this).attr("rel"))
})
$("div.links a").click(function(){
var index=$(this).index();
$("div.otherlinks a:eq("+index+")").trigger("click");
})
```